# SSIS - Why won't my Data Flow Task fail?

Tags: sql, ssis, package, archive

I've got a simple SSIS package that runs a 'foreach' loop, checking a folder for .csv files. It imports the contents of the CSV into a staging table where the columns map. On success of this, it moves the file to an archive folder appending the date. Where it fails, it is supposed to put the file into a failure folder.

However, i've tested with a random csv, that doesn't have column headings that match the mappings, and the data flow task DOESN'T fail & the file goes to the archive folder (of course the table isn't updated either). Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Here is the package:

[image]

Here is the data flow:

[image]

Comment: You probably have something set up wrong. Of course, with no code and no idea of what your actual SSIS package looks like that's about as far as I'm willing to speculate. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What is the detailed logic defining the control flow precedence constraint testing for failure?

Comment: Are you comparing the number of rows in the source CSV file with that expected to appear in the staging table?

Comment: Check your dataflow for the settings of these properties:   FailPackageOnFailure, FailParentOnFailure, MaximumErrorCount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I can do this.

Start with seven text files of input data, one of which contains error data.

[image]

The control flow executes like this.

[image]

The good files get moved to the ProcessedData folder.

[image]

The bad file gets moved to the ToReviewData folder.

[image]

The only setting you need to make is MaximumErrorCount on the Foreach Loop Container. Set this to a suitably high value.

[image]

I haven't changed any of the properties on the Load Cats task. In particular, you can see that FailPackageOnFailure is False; this is only required for checkpoints.

[image]

The precedence constraints are as you'd expect. Nothing clever here.

[image]

[image]

See training kit 70-463 > Chapter 4: Designing and Implementing Control Flow.

Comment: Thats good, thanks for the effort that you went to as well :).